# How to extract attachments from xml including name and size?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following data in an XML file

```
<attachment name="data.pdf" size="104302">
DATA
</attachment>
```

I would like to extract the full thing into a new xml but I am only getting

```
<attachment>
DATA
</attachment>
```

My xslt file has

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//attachment" >
      <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select="node()"` doesn't include attributes, only child nodes (elements, text nodes, comments and processing instructions).  But it would be much simpler just to replace the entire `for-each` with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="//attachment" />
```

Note however that this would not produce a well-formed XML output if there is more than one `attachment` element in the original input, because you'd end up with more than one root-level element in the result.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked. I was thinking something way to complex when it was something simple.